# How to Render Date Object on React App application?

Tags: reactjs, web, react-dom

I was learning React and tried to display current date. But I am getting this error.
I created a Date object and stored it in a variable and then displayed it on the h2 tag.
Here's My code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const curr_tim= new Date();
  console.log(curr_tim);
  return (
   <div className='container'>
    <h1>
      React Clock
    </h1>
    <h2>Current Date is:{curr_tim}</h2>
   </div>

  );
}
export default App;
```

and I am getting this as error.

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:1)
    at updateSlot (react-dom.development.js:15202:1)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:15349:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15821:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19174:1)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19924:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21618:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error suggested, curr_tim is an object and React can't render object on the UI. You can try to turn it to something like `new Date().toDateString()`, or any kind of date you would like. As long as it's a primitive type it would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with This,

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const curr_tim= new Date().toDateString();
  console.log(curr_tim);
  return (
   <div className='container'>
    <h1>
      React Clock
    </h1>
    <h2>Current Date is:{curr_tim}</h2>
   </div>

  );
}
export default App;
```

Or With This,

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const curr_tim= new Date();
  console.log(curr_tim);
  return (
   <div className='container'>
    <h1>
      React Clock
    </h1>
    <h2>Current Date is:{curr_tim.toDateString()}</h2>
   </div>

  );
}
export default App;
```